# difference between angular js and java script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Please Reply**
 - what is the role of angular js?
 - what is the role of java script?
 - when use angularjs 
 - when use java script
 - which one is powerfull

Comment: If you don't know the difference, then you probably shouldn't be looking at Angular. JavaScript is a code language that can run in a browser. Angular is a framework, a set of JavaScripts that fulfill a specific purpose.

Comment: Angularjs is a framework of javascript, there is nothing called 'more powerful' between these two, you just get what you need or what fits your requirement.
For these types of question, you can search on google, and for asking in stackoverflow, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. JavaScript is a programming language. Frameworks like AngularJS try to provide alternative workflows which are often easier to develop with than plain JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Angular and jQuery are both libraries/frameworks *written in* **Javascript**. Asking for me to compare Angular to Javascript is like asking for a comparison between bread and flour.

However, the browser APIs for DOM manipulation are implemented with a fundamentally different idea to Angular, so I'm going to assume that this is what your assignment is expecting you to identify.

The key point to focus on is that the paradigm is fundamentally different. Angular takes a **declarative** approach, whereas both the DOM and jQuery are **imperative**.

## Declarative

> A style of building the structure and elements of computer programs, that expresses the logic of a computation without describing its control flow. [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)]

A declarative language is one in which you describe what you want, not how it should be done. This is very much Angular's approach with directives.

## Imperative

> [A style] in which algorithms are implemented in terms of explicit steps. [[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declarative_programming)]

When we write code using the DOM APIs or jQuery, we have to detail the "how" of the process.

Let's take data binding as an example. We want to bind a value from a text input, into a label.

#### With the DOM

```
<input type='text' id='bind-input'>
<label id='bind-output'></label>
```

And our Javascript:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var input = document.getElement('bind-input'),
      output = document.getElement('bind-output');

  input.addEventListener('change', function() {
    output.innerText = input.value;
  });
});
```

We have to very specifically explain what we need the browser to do. We have to listen to certain events, make sure that the DOM is loaded, keep track of our element's IDs, all just to update our label whenever our input changes.

#### With jQuery

```
<input type='text' id='bind-input'>
<label id='bind-output'></label>
```

We still need some Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input = $('#bind-input'),
      $output = $('#bind-output');

  $input.on('change', function() {
    $output.html($input.value());
  });
});
```

As you can see, this is pretty similar to the DOM approach. We have to explain to the browser *exactly* what we want it to do.

#### With Angular

```
<input type='text' ng-model='bound'>
<label ng-bind='bound'></label>
```

We don't even need to write any code for this to work with Angular! (Obviously we'd need an empty controller somewhere, but you get the idea).

The declarative approach is primarily a way for us to abstract away from the implementation details. Angular directives make it very easy to wrap up these common behaviours into small reusable components than can be applied to our HTML in a declarative way.